# Excel: How to count number of distinct values that meet multiple conditions - single cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic, distinct-values

| Client Number | Matter Number | Address | Physical Files | Electronic Files | If any? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1000101 | Addy1 | No | No | 0 |
| 10001 | 1000102 | || | No | No | 0 |
| 10002 | 1000201 | NULL |  |  | 1 |
| 10003 | 1000301 | Addy3 | Yes | Yes | 1 |
| 10004 | 1000401 | Addy4 | No | No | 0 |
| 10004 | 1000402 | || | Yes | No | 1 |
| 10004 | 1000403 | || | No | No | 0 |
| 10005 | 1000501 | Addy5 | No | Yes | 1 |
| 10006 | 1000601 | Addy6 | No | No | 0 |

I have a large excel sheet that for all intents and purposes looks like this example ^^

The "If any?" column has this formula: `=IF(AND('Physical Files'="No", 'Electronic Files'="No"),0,1)`

I'm trying to count the number of clients that have no physical or electronic files. Each client has a distinct Client Number, but some appear multiple times with multiple matters. If there is a client address on file, then it is noted as well as whether there are physical and/or electronic files. If there is no address, the Physical/Electronic columns are left blank.

| Distinct Client #s | Files? |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 0 |
| 10002 | 1 |
| 10003 | 1 |
| 10004 | 1 |
| 10005 | 1 |
| 10006 | 0 |

Right now I have a generated list of distinct client #s using `=UNIQUE()`. In the neighboring column I have this formula: `=SUM(FILTER(M2:M10, H2:H10=O2))` --> Column M = "If any?" and Column H = "Client Number" in the example sheet, and Column O = "Distinct Client #s".

From that, I've used a COUNTIF for when the "Files?" Column = 0 -- the result is 2, which is correct, but I'm trying to find a way to get that result without having to make a list of the distinct client numbers. Is there a way to do this in a single cell?

Comment: Your screenshots don't show the column/row names so it is difficult to connect the formula with the sample. Please try to put the input data and expected output in table markdown format it helps others to reproduce it. Check this: [Tables Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: Assuming data to start in `A1`, the long way round could be `=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,C2:C10,"NULL")+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,C2:C10,"<>NULL",D2:D10,"Yes")+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,C2:C10,"<>NULL",E2:E10,"Yes"))=0)))`

Comment: @Annika I provided an answer, but reviewing again your question it is not clear to me the connection with the **Address** column. I provided a solution for: Count **If any?** values per unique client. Please clarify it, in case I need to update my answer. Thanks

Comment: Please be aware of your `IF` condition on how it was defined, per your statement you are assigning `1` to the opposite case: "I'm trying to count the number of clients that have no physical or electronic files. Each client has a distinct Client Number". Not relevant for your question, but maybe for your real problem.

Comment: @DavidLeal Yes - I wanted to assign `0` to the matters with no files so when I `SUM` the **If any?** values for each client number, I can find the clients with no files based on the condition that the `SUM` is <1 if that makes sense?

Comment: I see, why not to inverse the condition as follow: `=IF(AND('Physical Files'="No", 'Electronic Files'="No"),1,0)` then you count/sum the ones. Did you check my answer, is this what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in cell `H2`:

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A10), SUMIFS(F2:F10,A2:A10,UNIQUE(A2:A10)))
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

If you don't have `HSTACK` available in your excel version, then you can use the following:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2}, UNIQUE(A2:A10), SUMIFS(F2:F10,A2:A10,UNIQUE(A2:A10)))
```

Comment: Thank you! The `SUMIFS` helps me. Is there a way to nest `SUMIFS` into a `COUNTIF` function or something to that effect? I want to be able to count all the 0 values in one cell if possible. I tried `=COUNTIF(SUMIFS(F2:F10, A2:A10, UNIQUE(A2:A10)), 0)` but I keep getting an error.

Comment: You can also use `COUNT` with `IF` as follow: `=COUNT(IF(SUMIFS(F2:F10,A2:A10,UNIQUE(A2:A10))=0,1,""))` both `COUNT`/`SUM` don't have a range constraint like RACONs functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(        
            (MMULT(               
                   COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,D2:D10,{"Yes",""})+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,E2:E10,{"Yes",""}),
                   {1;1})
                         >0)
             /COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10)
             )
```

MMULT calculates which ID's count one or more matches of `Yes` or `""` in column D or E divided by the count of the ID.
So if you SUM those it will sum to 1 per ID, so the result of the formula is the count of unique ID's meeting given conditions.

**Edit:** I read it's the other way around; then subtract the previous from the total unique count:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10))-
     SUMPRODUCT(
                (MMULT(
     
                       COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,D2:D10,{"Yes",""})+COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,E2:E10,{"Yes",""}),
                       {1;1})
                             >0)
       
                /COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10)
                )
```